# Android native C++ function call cause application crash

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I have Android app, where I need to use C++ code. But I realised, I have problem to call C++ function. I have read something about it and tried to write something, I thought it could work. Here is my code:

```
private native int test(int a);
private void process() {
    int ret=test(5);
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(ret), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And my C++ code is:

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_woodem_woodem_1opencvgrains_Main_test(JNIEnv *env, jint a) 
{
    return a*a;
}
```

Of course, my real function is much more complicated and I need to pass about 6 arguments, but I hope, this can illustrate.

NOTE: Even this code doesn't work to me.

My application crash immediately after calling process(). Could you please advice me, what am I doing wrong? Compiler tells me nothing and I have no idea, where the problem is.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: We need the LogCat of the crash. Also where is the Java code to load the native llibrary ?

Comment: Given the Java code `private native int test();`, there's no way the native function call definition would be `JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_woodem_woodem_1opencvgrains_Main_test(JNIEnv *env, jint a)`.  Post the header file created by `javah`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle could you please tell me which file? Address and name of file. I am using AndroidStudio.

Comment: @google2 try declaring your Java function as "private static native int test(int a);" or declare your C function in a way that it takes one more parameter for your Java object.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting about the second argument. For example method `void test()` will have JNI signature `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java..._test(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)`. In your case, edit signature to `(JNIEnv *env. jobject thiz, jint a)`.

Edit

The previous version showed a signature for a static function. I've updated it to match instance function.

For static signature is `(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz)`.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your native function as `private native int test();` passing an integer argument to it. 
It should be `private native int test(int num);`